How to handle Authentication Popup in Chrome using Selenium WebDriver
I have seen numerous posts about how to pass in credentials through the url or using AutoIt to handle the authentication popup, but I simple want to cancel out of it or not have it pop up at all as my actual login appears anyways.
Locally I have added the url to my trusted sites, so I don't see the popup at all. My issue is that I am running my tests using Jenkins on a Windows node and I can't modify the internet options on the Windows node. All the options are disabled.
Is there anyway to pass in that it's a trusted site through my Chrome options that I set?

from the text of your question this sounds like domain-level authentication.  Trusted Sites/Local Intranet zones are set at OS level.  (internet options)

@browsermator, yes that is correct. But I'm not able to change the internet options on a windows node, so trying to determine if there is a way to do it through the code.

you can't do that through any browser per say... the OS has to know that's a local domain since that's the tie in to domain credentials.  It will automatically trust certain domain names that it knows are local though.  I think machine names should be good by default.  (instead of using a fully qualified domain name)

I've never used Jenkins, but maybe this plugin would help?: https://plugins.jenkins.io/NegotiateSSO/
